# how to make a ul li css menu with variable space between items

Tags: css, menu, html-lists, padding, margin

The idea is to make a menu with a fixed amount of items. Each of the items must have a fixed padding on them to make them look decent when placing a border around them. (so far so good)
But these items must be spread out in a div with a fixed size, spaced evenly - the items themselves won't be the same size as this is dependent on the text within these items.

What I can't figure out is how to make sure that the items are on 1 line with a dynamic (more or less) evenly spacing between them within a fixed div (in my case 1000px). The first item should be lined out to the left edge of the div. The last item should be lined out to the right edge of the div.

Below is what I have so far. This already puts the padding and border on it, but I can't set a margin: 0 auto on it, well I can, but it doesn't do anything. The main issue is that the spacing in between should be dynamic because the items tend to jump upon zooming the browser which in turn messes up the alignment of the outer items and even makes some items jump to the next line. That's why (zooming messes things up - especially with fixed widths) I'm reluctant to put an actual width on each of the items (I know I need a width to use margin: 0 auto properly, but even when I do use a width, it doesn't seem to do what I want it to do).

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-1"><a href="" >Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-2"><a href="" class="">Nieuws</a></li>
        <li class="menu-3"><a href="" class="">Producten</a></li>
        <li class="menu-4"><a href="" class="">Algemene informatie</a></li>
        <li class="menu-5"><a href="" class="">Promoties</a></li>
        <li class="menu-6"><a href="" class="">Algemene voorwaarden</a></li>
        <li class="menu-7"><a href="" class="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#navigation ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
    width:1000px;   
    display:block;
}

#navigation li {
    float: left;
    display:inline;
}

#navigation li a {
    padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
    float:right;

    display: block;
    border: 0.1em solid #dcdce9;
    color: #6d6f71;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center; 
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#navigation{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: The flexbox model will solve this, eventually.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest would be to use a table instead of li items : you can define the table width and the cell widths will be automatically computed.

You can choose to give them width in % to have them equal or decide to let them proportionally adapted.

No need to be afraid of tables : sometimes they do the job simpler.

Comment: According to the original specification, you'll need to alternate menu cells (which need to shrink wrap) with empty cells (which need to fight with each other for the remaining space).

Comment: or to play with border and margin, or spans inside the cells, depends on the final desired effect. But of course supplementary cells may be useful.

Comment: I've always considered using tables for non table needs as bad practise, but it's worth considering since no other solution has come close to what I need yet

Comment: That was an exaggeration : the problem mainly appears when you use tables for ordinary layout (a lot of people were slow to transition to css). But if you're careful, there is no need to avoid the tool which is the best for the problem in a precise case.

Answer (score 1):

Using table display modes: http://jsfiddle.net/pnUdp/1/

```
#navigation {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display:table;
    width:1000px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#navigation ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
    display:table-row-group;
}

#navigation li{
    display:table-cell;
    border: 0.1em solid #dcdce9;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#navigation li a{
    padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
    display:block;
    color: #6d6f71;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center; 
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

I am unsure of how cross-browser this is though...

Comment: How do I get the spacing to be evenly between the items dynamically? This code puts the items into a single row without a spacing between the items. I've achieved the same effect with a float:left version of the menu, but I couldn't figure out how to achieve auto spacing between the items

Comment: I adjusted the css to allow spacing between the elements: http://jsfiddle.net/pnUdp/7/ - Be warned though that if any of the text breaks to 2 lines, things get weird.